# how to get all devices information between 2 devices

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ping

I've 2 devices My-PC and another-PC

another-PC are connected to switch which connected to main switch with-in the same LAN

My question is how to get all devices information such as (IP,MAC,Serial Number) from My-PC to another-PC

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I've tried to get information like `MAC address` but just for target device (another-PC) not switches in between

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation for the System.Management namespace on MSDN. All you need is in there. There are also numerous examples out there if you search for retrieving WMI information with C#. A small example:

```
    using System;
    using System.Management;
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
             static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                  // create management class object
                  ManagementClass mc = new 
                  ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
                  //collection to store all management objects
                  ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
                  if (moc.Count != 0)
                  {
                      foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
                      {
                           // display general system information
                           Console.WriteLine("\nMachine Make: {0}", mo["Manufacturer"].ToString());
                      }
                  }
                  //wait for user action
                  Console.ReadLine();
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Not really an answer, should just be a comment.

Comment: Hope it's an answer now. The question is very broad as the different types of information will be nested in various WMI classes. This needs to be researched by the poster depending on what they desire to retrieve.

Comment: I'm trying to get devices information between source and destination device in my case there is 2 switches which my packet goes throw main switch to secondary switch to target device

Comment: @BlackRoot the answer remains valid as long as the devices are on the same subnet or there is a route from one to another and you know the ip of the target computer. If you do not know the ip of the target, you could discover devices on the subnet by simply attempting a ping to each address in that subnet.

Comment: @BlackRoot check the System.Net.NetworkInformation Ping class. The documentation on MSDN gives you some good examples for both synchronous and asynchronous calls.

Comment: I've used the Ping class but I'm trying to check System.Managment namespace